# Boost::Asio chat example program --- how to implement private chat

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm learning boost::asio by working on the chat example application. In the example, it sends message to all participant. I want to add a private chat function into it (private chat using server as relay).

To keep the question simple, let's say we only have two clients, A and B. To 
What I thought was that if I save A and B's socket into a map when they are connected. After that, if A want to talk to B, i search map for A's socket (and thus find B's socket), then send the message down to B's socket.

However, it seems a fairly difficult task. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is not a difficult task. You have to read in the documentation more and check examples over the internet. Google spits out a lot of example usages. Start off with what you've mentioned, and try a chatroom then. One server multiple clients. After that you're quite familar with boost::asio.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly.

If you are looking at the c++11 example, then you can do the following:

1. Add a new property (an id) for a chat_participant in `chat_server.cpp`
2. Add a `register_client` function in `chat_client.cpp`, which registers a id to each client.
3. Change the following lines of code in `chat_room::deliver`

   ```
   for (auto participant: participants_) {
       if(participant->id == recipient_id)
           participant->deliver(msg);
   }
   ```

The above is just to give you a general idea of how to do this.

Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.

Comment: What if I don't modify the client.cpp? Can this be done on server side only? Is it possible to create a std::map and save two client's socket into the map? I used this kind of approach in normal socket application because the socket was an integer. However, it seems hard to do it in Boost ASIO since socket is an object...

Comment: Just checked the code again. There was an issue with the std::map. I corrected it. It is now support private chat!